# update xml using xdocument

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to update XML using XDocument
where Trans_mast is my table name in which text_xml is there
I dont get any idea how to do that as i am gettin error  also
here is the code:

```
 var names = (from Trans_Mast in XDocument.Load(p.text.ToString())
                 .Descendants("Text")
                 .Where(c => c.Attribute("group").Value.Equals(groupname))
                 select Trans_Mast).ToList();

foreach (var item in names)
{
    // xele.Value = content;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your XML file?

Comment: What was the error message exactly and which line triggered that error?

Comment: @har07 there is no err but my XML is not updated so what I have to do next

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are mixing both query & method syntax, stick with one if possible. Here, I am using method syntax:-

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(p.text.ToString());
var names = xdoc.Descendants("Text")
                .Where(c => c.Attribute("group").Value.Equals(groupname));
```

Then you can use either [SetAttributeValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [SetElementValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setelementvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to update attribute or element value resp. like this:-

```
foreach (var item in names)
{
    item.SetElementValue("yourelementName","value");
}
```

**Update:**
Finally save the `xdoc` Object:-

```
xdoc.Save(p.text.ToString());
```

Comment: from this my XML will update or I have to write query for that??

Comment: it shows err of illegal path at xdoc.save(); @Rahul Singh

Comment: Hey buddy I am not sure what 'p.text' is...all you need to do is from where you are loading the xml file using xdocument.Load method, pass the same path in Save method as well.

Comment: What if my columns data type is xml and i want to save this??? bcz database is  not changed bcz of xml datatype

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about, as far as updation of XML is concerned, it will work.

Comment: in my database data type of that column is XML otherwise it will work by doin this